# Dual Axes Column Chart scaling issue for column chart

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng, dotnethighcharts

I am having trouble with dual axes column chart. Its not scaling properly for second y axis. I want know how scaling works at secondary y axis (i.e. for column chart). So I can make my data visible on graph. I have through solutions but I am not able to get to root cause.
    I have tried to put this scenario in following fiddle.
    I am providing 2 images where one image is gives expected view. Scaling is optimum. While another image is has map which is not scaled properly.[Expected Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGKDn.png) [Unexpected Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuTvZ.png)
    Thanks in advance!

Comment: The link is missing from your post. A description of what you mean by "not scaling properly", and what would qualify as "properly" would be helpful too.

Comment: Please refer to this link
http://jsfiddle.net/gzgewwto/2/

I will say it still renders properly. But in my actual application scaling for 2nd y axis is not proper.
If max series data is 7000 then limits goes to 19k or something. In some cases it is worst than that. I want to know how scaling for 2nd axis works.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually solved by adding `alignTicks: false` at the chart object level.
You can also add `gridlineWidth: 0` to your 2nd axis to alleviate any issues with misaligned gridlines.

Updated fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/gzgewwto/3/

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.alignTicks

Comment: Hey. I have tried that solution but it wont be good in my scenario. Most of the times user refer the ticks for understanding of levels.

Comment: The ticks are still there, so they can still refer to them. Really though, best solution is not to have two unrelated axes on a single chart. A 2-chart solution is almost always best.